# How to hide a section in a table view controller with static cells?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with static cells, with 3 sections, and a segmented control with 2 buttons.
I would like to achieve the following behavior:

- when button 1 is pressed hide section 2
- when button 2 is pressed hied section 3

I cannot find a solution to this. 
Any tip is useful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, just make sure you set your UITableViewDelegate, and you can use heightForRowAtIndexPath: (and similar for headers and footers) to show/hide the cells by setting their height to 0.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        if (self.shouldShowSection2) {
            return 44.0f;
        }else{
            return 0.0f;
        }
    }else if (indexPath.section == 3) {
        if (self.shouldShowSection3) {
            return 44.0f;
        }else{
            return 0.0f;
        }
    }else{
        return 44.0f;
    }
}
```

Then just define some logic within your IBAction to change these BOOLs around in between tableview's begin/end updates, and the table will show/hide the sections you want.

```
- (IBAction)toggleSegment:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    //  change boolean conditions for what to show/hide
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: From what I've read, UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource should not be used with static cells. Am I wrong? I am a beginner so, if I say something stupid, excuse me.

Comment: @user2611691 Kind of. AFAIK you'll be fine as long as you don't attempt to use cellForRowAtIndexPath, numberOfRows.., or numberOfSections..

Comment: @user2611691 This might also be of interest: https://github.com/xelvenone/StaticDataTableViewController